# Arbitrary decimal value of $A(n)=\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, decimal-expansion

For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ consider the number
$$A(n)=\left(1+x\right)^n\bigg{|}_{x=\frac{1}{10}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}10^{-k}$$
which we have expanded by the Taylor series. It is found that
$$a_1=\binom{n}{1},\,a_2=\binom{n}{2},\,\dots ,\,a_k=\binom{n}{k},\dots$$
which I thought gives the explicit formula for the $k$th digit below the decimal point of any number with the form
$$A(n)=\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^n$$
but take for example $A(5)=(11/10)^5=1.\color{red}{6}{1}051$ and say we want to find the $1$st digit below the decimal, highlighted red. We see $a_1={}_5C_{1}=5$ which isn't $6$ as $a_2={}_5C_2=10$ contributes $1$ to the next digit. My question is, is it possible to find the $k$th decimal value of $A(n)$ by means of coefficient extraction from some generating function?

**Edit 1:** To clarify, I am not looking for a generating function, but some explicit formula for the $k$th digit below the decimal point of $A(n)$. Now, using generating functions to find the formula is of course fine.

Comment: You have an explicit formula for $A(n)$, so you can easily find an explicit formula for $A(n)$'s $k$-th digit by "cutting out" this digit (via modulo and rounding operations for example). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndreasLenz That would obviously work, and that is what at least two of the answers do below (I'm not even sure about the third). But I was hoping for something simpler (without the use of modulo), like some coefficients of a Taylor series etc. I understand this might not be plausible though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want the formula to get to the $r$th digit from starting

Let $$S=\sum_{i=0}^{n-r+1} (10)^{i} \binom{n}{i}$$

Let $P=S\mod{(10^{[n\log_{10}(11)]-r+2})}$

Let $\log_{10}P=Q$

let $\{Q\}$=R ..............$($where $\{Q\}$ denotes fractional part of $Q$$)$

Let $10^R=V$

Let $[V]=U$........(Where $[V]$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to $V$)

then the $r$th digit from beginning of decimals of $(1.1)^n =U$

finally $$U(n,r)=\left[10^{\left \{{\log_{10}((\sum_{i=0}^{n-r+1}\binom{n}{i}10^i)\mod10^{[nlog_{10}(11)]-r+2})}  \right \}}\right]$$

where

$[x]=$ Greatest integer less than or equal to $x$

$\{x\}=$ Fractional part of $x$

Comment: Sorry I do not really get your formula. You have too may variables, can you simplify it?

Comment: @shmurda,I have added combined form of $U$ in the answer to clarify it

Comment: Have you seen this summary of how to use MathJax to write formulas on this site?  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Why did you end up writing everything except for the actual formula in Mathjax?

Answer (score 0):

First I focus on finding the first $k$ th digit of $11^n$.

Before you start this exercise, it is helpful to note that you can evaluate the last $p$ digits of $11^n$ in a much easier way, it is simply the last $p$ digits of:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{n \choose i} 10^i$$

(Consider the binomial expansion $(10+1)^n$).

Now, recall from number theory that the number of digits in radix $10$ in some number $a$ is given by $\lfloor \log_{10}(a)\rfloor + 1$

So the k-th digit from the start is the $\lfloor n\log_{10}(11)\rfloor + 2 - k$ th digit from the end. So in order to find the first $k$-th digit from the left of $11^n$, you need to evaluate the last digit of the integral part of:

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n\log_{10}(11)\rfloor + 1 - k} {n\choose i}10^i}{10^{\lfloor n\log_{10}(11)\rfloor + 1 - k }}
$$

An approximation for $\log_{10}{11}$ is given by $1.0413$. So in the case given in your question, you just want to find the second digit of $11^5$, so it evaluates to finding:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{4} {5\choose i}10^i = 61051
$$

Hence, the second digit being $6$, not $5$.

Now if we consider $(1.1)^n$, the $k$ th digit after the decimal is simply the $n - k+ 1$ the digit from the end.

So the final answer to your problem: the first $k$ th digit after the decimal of $1.1^n$ is the **last digit from left** of:

$$
\lfloor\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n - k} {n\choose i}10^i}{10^{n-k}}\rfloor
$$

or simply:

$$
\lfloor\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n - k} {n\choose i}10^i}{10^{n-k}}\rfloor \bmod 10
$$

Although I do not find to be very useful, I think it answers your problem.

Comment: Although this shows how to calculate the $k$th digit, it isn't much different from just writing out $11^k$ and looking for the correct digit, which is also what one of the answer below does.

Comment: I am looking for an explicit formula. To give a sense, your "formula" gives
$$\sum_{i=0}^{4} {5\choose i}10^i = 61051$$
and we infer $6$ by looking at the first digit from the left. However, the formula itself is far from giving the direct answer, that is $6$.

Comment: I see. I will try to work out something that may be helpful here.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the series expansion of the map $$f := z \mapsto \frac{1}{1-11z}$$
around $z=0$. You should find
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left ( 11z \right) ^ k$$

Therefore, the $m$th digit of $(11/10)^\ell$ is the $(m-1)$th digit of the coefficient of $z^\ell$ in $f$. Can you figure out how to compute that? You should note that after $\ell \ge 5$, you start to have overlapping effects from the binomial sum across digits.

Comment: Is the variable in the sum supposed to be $z$?

Comment: Your answer is pretty much exactly my question. In my question I use $k$ instead of $m$, but I find a series where the $k$th coefficient is the $k$th decimal value. I also use the example $n=5$ ($l=5$ in yours) to show the overlaps with the coefficients; this is precisely the problem I am trying to address in my question.

Comment: you asked for a generating function for your powers, there it is, 1/(1-11x)...

Comment: As an example, can you compute the $4$th number below the decimal point of $A(8)$?

Comment: I am asking you this because then you will see your procedure is exactly the same as the one I've outlined in my question.

Comment: To compute, you don't use the generating function. The only relevant generating function in this context is that of organization. To _calculate_ you simply need the 4th digit of $11^8$

Comment: $4$th digit of $11^8=214358881$. Are you counting the digits up or down? Either way the "$4$th" digit you are talking about is $3$ or $8$, which isn't the $4$th number below the decimal of $A(8)=2.143\color{red}{5}8881$. This is because you forgot to account for the integer part of the number, so really, we need to count $5$ numbers down.

Comment: Now may I ask, is your method any different from just writing out $A(n)$ and looking for the right decimal? In essence it looks the same to me.

Comment: Correct, to calculate a coefficient of $x^n$ in my $f$ is the same as calculating $A(n)$. It is a generating function organizing the individual problems themselves. They don't help you solve $A(n)$.

Comment: Ok then I'm sorry but this answer is not helpful.

Comment: Do you see why it only makes sense to use a generating function to cleanly organize your problems, rather than using a generating function to solve an individual one? It's exactly how I said it was going to be in my answer, and yet you just leave this thread to die. Whatever